# Issue with Java HashMap Assignment

Tags: java

For some reason this function in my project is failing:

```
public void SetPlayersLineups(HashMap<Integer, Player> _players, 
    ArrayList<Integer> _lineup, boolean isAwayTeam) {

    System.out.println(_players.get(2)); //works properly
    System.out.println(_players.get(2).getNumberHits()); //null pointer exception

    if (isAwayTeam) {
        this.awayLineup = _lineup;
        this.awayPlay = _players;
    } else {
        this.homeLineup = _lineup;
        this.homePlay = _players;
    }

}

/* from Player class */

public int getNumberHits() {

    return this.hits;

}
```

I have a Player class, with a member get function getNumberHits().  The this.awayPlay and this.homePlay properties are not being set correctly.  So I debugged with the System.out.println statements.  The first returns a Player instance correctly.  But when I call the get function I get a null pointer exception.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, one thing at a time. First off, you're printing `_players.get(2).getNumberHits()` and getting a NPE. Either `_players.get(2)` returns `null`, or `getNumberHits()` does something that throws an NPE. What cannot be the case is that `_players2` is `null` since you already said that worked.

So, you need to look into what's wrong with the object `_players` you are being passed. I would suggest you try setting a breakpoint and analysing the object with your IDE (e.g. Eclipse or Netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

If `hits` is declared as an `Integer` and is `null`, this method:

```
Integer hits; // default value of objects is null

public int getNumberHits() {
    return hits;    
}
```

will throw an NPE due to [auto unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), because the method actually compiles as:

```
public int getNumberHits() {
    return hits.intValue();    
}
```

Either assign a value to `hits`:

```
Integer hits = 0;
```

or give `hits` the type of `int`, whose default value is `0`, not `null`:

```
int hits;
```

Comment: I have hits assigned as an integer property declaration: private int hits = 0;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that hits is null, and Java tries to autobox hits (which is Integer) to int, and produces NullPointerException